# Using a css-filter on a child element to affect its parent

Tags: html, css, svg, css-filters

Is there any way of adding a filter (CSS or other type) to an element so this filter then effectively applies to the element below it.

I have an element with reduced opacity, that sits on top of a background image.  I would like the element with reduced opacity to basically apply a black and white filter to the part of the element directly below it (effectively working as a mask). In the example below this means that the part of the image below the white box has the filter applied to it.

https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/zWjWxo

Two things to note:

1) Because I'm using vh and vw units and the layout changes dependent on device / window size, I can't slice the image in photoshop or similar and then add or  align it separately.

2) The image placeholder service I'm using serves up random images, and sometimes the image in the example is black and white - please don't let this confuse the issue.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#row-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://loremflickr.com/320/240");
  background-size: cover;
}

#inner {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="row-1">
  <div id="inner">
    <p id="text">Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible in css and html.

Comment: @MobyMotion I've edited the question to also include SVG, which I think is my only hope

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no. But there is a non-standard -webkit-back-drop filter that works in iOS, but it's only available in other browsers behind an experimental flag.

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/css-backdrop-filters--cms-27314

(SVG 1.1 had a mechanism to do this, but the spec was poorly written and only IE10+ ever implemented it (and they may have backed it out))

Comment: OK Thanks Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#row-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://loremflickr.com/320/240");
  background-size: cover;
}

#inner {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}
```

```html
<div id="row-1">
  <div id="inner">
    <p id="text"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI Temani, I did try different blendmodes but it creates a different effect and I want the white box to stay as it is with the subtle opacity so the text stands out (which is also the reason I want the cross over area to be black and white).  Thanks for the suggestion though.  I don't think what I want is possible.

Answer (score -3):

Please, try [this solution I have made on Codepen](https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/oqdmvX). You can play around with the Z-index & opacity in `background-color`.

It uses the `:after` pseudo element to make some sort of filter. Being stretched all over the div with an absolute position, everything underneath it will be affected.

I hope it can help you!

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1486/23990047223_5b7a0c82e8_b.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
//  change color opacity here!
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

// styling
.box p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```